# How to register an Asp.net web service in a windows server service bus

Tags: .net, web-services, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am fairly new in service bus for window server. I want to register an .asmx web service in the service bus subscription such that if any new message arises in the service bus, the service bus will automatically call the web service.. Is this possible?
Is this something similar to Binding in service bus?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.  You could however, write a windows service consumer which consumed SB messages.  This could listen to SB either via the .net Client or WCF net messaging binding (both TCP) or by polling the REST API (over Http). Then once you receive one of those messages, your windows service could post the message out to your asmx web service.